# ConTeXt: Wrong mathmatrix spacing between rows in startalign-environment

Tags: spacing, align, context, matrices, context-mkiv

When using a mathmatrix (e.g. for vectors) in between `\startalign` and `\stopalign`, the spacing between rows becomes too large. I'm running Mark IV and the problem exists on [live.contextgarden.net](http://live.contextgarden.net/) as well.

Is there anything I can do about this?

MWE:

```
\setupmathmatrix[left={\left[\,}, right={\,\right]}]

\starttext

\startformula
  \startmathmatrix \NC 1 \NR \NC 2 \NR \NC 3 \NR \stopmathmatrix
\stopformula

\startformula \startalign
  \NC \startmathmatrix \NC 1 \NR \NC 2 \NR \NC 3 \NR \stopmathmatrix \NR
\stopalign \stopformula

\stoptext
```

which gives

[image]

**Edit:** Adding `\noalign{\blank[-6pt]}` between each row in the matrix solves my problem and I can do that programmatically, so I'll be fine. A nicer solution would be nice though.

Comment: Untested. The syntax for each row of a matrix is matrices is `\NC ... \NR`

Comment: Sorry about that, is it right now? I'm still experiencing the problem.

Comment: I can confirm that this is a bug. Please report it to the ConTeXt mailing list.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This bug has been fixed once it was reported to the context mailing list. On the current beta (2013.09.01), I get the following correct output.

[image]

Comment: Fantastic! Thank you very much for your work and response!